# How to SUM data row in SQLite?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am new here and want to ask regarding android studio using sqLite. I want to SUM all the data that store in a column and display it in textview. I am new in programming and I little bit confused bcs it keep not showing the total sum of the column of the  table. here is the code that I build my self. thank you.

//HERE IS THE DB CREATION

```
public void createdb(){
    db1 = this.openOrCreateDatabase("dbshops",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
    String sqlcreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS shops" +
            "(ITEMS VARCHAR NOT NULL,PRICE DOUBLE);";
    db1.execSQL(sqlcreate);
}
```

// HERE IS THE METHOD THAT I USED FOR SUM PRICE COLUMN:

```
public void calculatePrice(){
    results = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resulttextView);
    try {
        String sqlcalculate = "SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM shops";
        db1.execSQL(sqlcalculate);
        Cursor c = db1.rawQuery(sqlcalculate, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            results.setText("TOTAL PRICE = " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("price")));
            return;
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
    }
}
```

Comment: Kling Klang yeah sorry, I'm doing the practice since yesterday. my mistake :)

Comment: Check out my answer below.

Comment: [refer this ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582538/2794507)

Comment: @HardikVasani arigatooooooooooooo!!! it works!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing the terms `row` and `column`.

Try:

```
String sqlcalculate = "SELECT SUM(PRICE) AS PriceTotal FROM shops";
```

and then

```
results.setText("TOTAL PRICE = " + c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("PriceTotal")));
```

By doing so, you are creating an "alias" (calculated) column named `PriceTotal` and then you are retrieving it.

---

By the way, remove this useless line

```
db1.execSQL(sqlcalculate);
```

Comment: yeah, thank you. it still doesn't work. ill attach my dbcreate