# Return sum(item_price) from sqlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, sum, android-cursor

I'm trying to get the sum from the specific column in the database. I think my query is ok but I think it's something wrong with receiving it back. Please direct me to the right way.

Thank you so much in advance.

```
public static double countPrice (SQLiteDatabase db, int selectedID){
    String[] sumPrice = new String[]{"sum(item_price)"};
    String selection = "list_id =? AND item_flag =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(selectedID), String.valueOf(0)};

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, sumPrice, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    double result = c.getCount();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20582538/4168607

Comment: Thanks your reply, I will try and get back with the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Cursor `getCount()` method which will return the number of rows, which would be 1 as the query is returning an aggregate (i.e. the sum).

Instead you need to

- a) move to the first row in the cursor and then
- b) read/extract the data from the respective column using an appropriate Cursor `get???` method.

As such your code could be :-

```
public static double countPrice (SQLiteDatabase db, int selectedID){
    String[] sumPrice = new String[]{"sum(item_price)"};
    String selection = "list_id =? AND item_flag =?";
    String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(selectedID), String.valueOf(0)};

    Cursor c = db.query(TABLE_NAME, sumPrice, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

    Double result = 0; // default value to signify nothing extracted
    if(c.moveToFirst()) { // move to the first(only) row in the Cursor
        result = c.getDouble(0); // get the value from the first column
    }
    c.close(); // Should always close cursors when done with them
    return result; // Ok to return extracted value (or default for nothing extracted)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, it works and I learn something new today, appreciated. =)

Answer (score 1):

You are returning cursor.getCount() which returns the number of rows but not the sum. [Android Cursor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount())

Use the following code :

```
Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(myColumn) FROM myTable", null);
if(cur.moveToFirst())
{

return cur.getInt(0);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply, i tried
 `double result;
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            result = c.getDouble(0);
        }

        return result;` 
but it give me error said the result is not initialized, any idea why?

Comment: actually i know why, my silly mistake =/,
But thanks so much for your help =) appreciated.